# Is $L^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ closed under almost sure convergence?

Tags: probability-theory

If we have a sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq L^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ (where $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a filtered probability space) that converges almost surely to some random variable $X$, does it then hold that $X\in L^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider *any* unbounded random variable $X\notin L^{\infty}(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ on your probability space (if any exists in the first place, that is). Define, for each positive integer $n$, $X_n\equiv\mathbf 1_{[X\leq n]}\cdot X$, where $\mathbf 1$ denotes the relevant indicator function. Clearly, $X_n$ is bounded for each $n$ and $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $X$ everywhere.

Comment: Thank you. If we assume additionally that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\|X_n\|_{\infty} <\infty$, then I think the statement is true?

Comment: @hannah Under that extra assumption, your original statement does follow, even if $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $X$ merely in probability (as opposed to almost surely). Can you prove it?

Comment: @hannah In fact, even convergence in distribution is sufficient.

Comment: If $(X_n)$ converges to $X$ in probability, we can wlog assume that it converges almost surely to $X$ (by passing to a subsequence). Then for almost every $\omega\in\Omega$, $|X(\omega)|=\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}|X_n(\omega)| \leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}\|X_n\|_{\infty} < \infty$.

Comment: @hannah After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).